# How to find a FormView nested in a listView from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, formview

I have a form view (FormView1) that is nested in a list view (listview1). The following code doesn't work cause FormView1 can't be found in the current context. Any tips?

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FormView1.DataItemCount == 0)
        {
            //do stuff;
        }           

    }
```

Comment: Hi. Why `FormView1_DataBound`?!

Answer (score 0):

Since the FormView is nested in a ListView, the ID of the FormView will be different for each item in the ListView. You can see this when you view the source of your page. It should look something like "listview1_ctrl0_FormView1", "listview1_ctrl1_FormView1", etc. This is why just simply "FormView1" is not found.

In your case, since you are using the `DataBound` handler of the FormView, the "sender" object in this case is the actual FormView. Cast this to a FormView and you should be good to go.

```
FormView FormView1 = (FormView)sender;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by finding the FormView as a control in the ListView as follows (in my case the ListView returns only one row):

```
protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        FormView = (FormView)e.Item.FindControl("FormView1"); 
        if (FormView1.DataItemCount == 0)
    {
        //do stuff;
    }          


    }
```